# Best way to animating wxDC paints

Tags: wxpython

I ask because in each painting exists a flicker effect. For example, I have a panel

```
panel = wx.Panel(self, -1)
panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.asd)
framesizer.Add(panel, flag=wx.EXPAND)
```

the callback is the *asd* function. Now I paint

```
dc = wx.PaintDC(panel)

[...] setting brush and misc

i = 10
for x in range(1, 100):
    i = i + x
    dc.Clear() # <- Look this... it's correct?
    dc.DrawRectangle(i,10,50,50)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to learn are double-buffering techniques. Fortunately, someone has already written up some good information on the subject on the wxPython wiki:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/DoubleBufferedDrawing

You will want to take a look at wx.BufferedPaintDC